# Access the locals available in the previous stack frame

Tags: python, inspect, contextmanager

I have a debug context manager where I would like to access the locals() at the time the context manager was initiated, without giving the locals as an argument. Is this possible?

I would like to do this in the general case, so that my Debug context manager can be used from any file importing `Debug`, not just in the tinkertoy example below.

Here is my minimal example:

```
import inspect

class Debug:
    def __init__(self):

        frames = inspect.stack()

        for frame in frames:
            line = frame.code_context[0]
            if "Debug" in line:
                break

        # I want to get the locals() at the time debug was called here!
        # give me i_will_be_in_the_locals
        raise Exception()

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    i_will_be_in_the_locals = 42
    with Debug():
        "hi"
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have already tried,? Is above the complete code?

Comment: I would like to access the locals() where Debug() was called where the Exception is now thrown. For that, you need to use insepect somehow, I'm sure, but I have been unable to figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The frame object is inside the "frame" variable you defined. To get the local variables for a frame object, you can call its f_locals attribute like this:

```
import inspect

class Debug:
    def __init__(self):

        frames = inspect.stack()

        for frame in frames:
            line = frame.code_context[0]
            if "Debug" in line:
                break

        # I want to get the locals() at the time debug was called here!
        # give me i_will_be_in_the_locals
        from pprint import pprint
        pprint(frame.frame.f_locals)

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    i_will_be_in_the_locals = 42
    with Debug():
        "hi"
```

The returned value is:

```
{'Debug': <class '__main__.Debug'>,
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__cached__': None,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': '/home/user1/main-projects/overflow/file.py',
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bbb44f7f0>,
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 '__spec__': None,
 'i_will_be_in_the_locals': 42,
 'inspect': <module 'inspect' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py'>}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Will look into it and see if this works in the general case and then accept :)

Comment: Thanks. I did try `f_locals` yesterday, but must have been confusing myself with the double `frame` (`frame.frame`). I probably did `frame.f_locals` XD.